# No Internet Access Message without killing app instance

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am currently working on sencha touch 2 project i want to display a Message "No Internet Access" without killing the app instance how can i achieve this using sencha touch 2 or through phonegap

Answer (score 0):

u can check connection to phonegap as below

navigator.network.connection.type Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for Cordova to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

</script>
```

A dialog box will report the network state.

For more info about it check **[PHONEGAP DOCUMENTATION ABOUT INTERNET CONNECTION](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection)**

Comment: how are we calling this checkConnection() function will this works when the app instance is running without killing the instance of the app

Comment: on DeviceReady function `checkConnection` has called..so u can call this function any time whenever u want to check internet connectivity

Comment: suppose i am inside the app i have connected to internet and i kept the app in idle if suddenly net is gone then how to call checkconnection() in sencha touch 2